# Not able to access Spring H2 Console

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, h2

I' working in a **Spring standalone** project. I' trying to use the H2 DB for fast testing. I'm having two problems that must have the same root:

First I'm not able to access to the H2 console which by default should be mapped to *http://localhost:8080/h2-console*.
[image]

I have H2 dependency in the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dreamseeker</groupId>
    <artifactId>CondoAdmin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>CondoAdmin</name>
    <description>Standalone project for condo administration</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.rgielen</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-weaver-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I added this line in the **application.properties** too: *spring.h2.console.enabled=true*

I suspect this is due the fact this is not a web app but I can't find in the internet any information which approves my hipotesys.

Secondly, I added a script to the resource directory to populate my H2 DB but an exception is jumping, which basically is complaining about an inexisting column:

*Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Columna "LASTNAME" no encontrada
Column "LASTNAME" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Person (id, name, lastname, dni, apartmentID) VALUES (1, 'Edgar', 'Hernandez', '26659514-k', '701') [42122-200]*

Here is the code of my entity class:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.dreamseeker.models.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 * @author Edgar Hernández
 *
 */
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String dni;
    private String apartmentID;

    public Person(String name, String lastName, String dni, String apartmentID) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.apartmentID = apartmentID;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public String getDNI() {
        return dni;
    }
    public String getApartmentID() {
        return apartmentID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Person[name=%d, last name='%s', dni='%s', apartmentID='%s']",
                name, lastName, dni, apartmentID);
    }

}
```

The script has this statement:

*INSERT INTO Person (id, name, lastname, dni, apartmentID) VALUES (1, 'Edgar', 'Hernandez', '26659514-k', '701');*

I can't see an error here. The field is declared correctly and referenced with the same name in the query...

This is the entire log:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m      [2m (v2.2.1.RELEASE)[0;39m

[2m2020-02-19 21:10:37.851[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting application on DESKTOP-I4H91H1 with PID 9236 (started by Edgar Hernández in C:\Users\Edgar Hernández\Documents\Programacion\GIT repos\CondoAdmin\Spring)
[2m2020-02-19 21:10:37.854[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2020-02-19 21:10:38.155[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2020-02-19 21:10:38.201[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 39ms. Found 2 repository interfaces.
[2m2020-02-19 21:10:38.465[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2020-02-19 21:10:38.539[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2020-02-19 21:10:38.576[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
[2m2020-02-19 21:10:38.627[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.Version                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.8.Final}
[2m2020-02-19 21:10:38.731[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.annotations.common.Version  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
[2m2020-02-19 21:10:38.831[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.dialect.Dialect           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
[2m2020-02-19 21:10:39.232[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.dreamseeker.models.entity.Person (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
[2m2020-02-19 21:10:39.315[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
[2m2020-02-19 21:10:39.320[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2020-02-19 21:10:39.341[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36ms.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/Edgar%20Hern%c3%a1ndez/Documents/Programacion/GIT%20repos/CondoAdmin/Spring/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO Person (id, name, lastname, dni, apartmentID) VALUES (1, 'Edgar', 'Hernandez', '26659514-k', '701'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Columna "LASTNAME" no encontrada
Column "LASTNAME" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Person (id, name, lastname, dni, apartmentID) VALUES (1, 'Edgar', 'Hernandez', '26659514-k', '701') [42122-200]
[2m2020-02-19 21:10:39.342[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
[2m2020-02-19 21:10:39.343[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
[2m2020-02-19 21:10:39.348[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36mConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2020-02-19 21:10:39.357[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m9236[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[JavaFX-Launcher][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/Edgar%20Hern%c3%a1ndez/Documents/Programacion/GIT%20repos/CondoAdmin/Spring/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO Person (id, name, lastname, dni, apartmentID) VALUES (1, 'Edgar', 'Hernandez', '26659514-k', '701'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Columna "LASTNAME" no encontrada
Column "LASTNAME" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Person (id, name, lastname, dni, apartmentID) VALUES (1, 'Edgar', 'Hernandez', '26659514-k', '701') [42122-200]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.dreamseeker.JavaFxApplication.init(JavaFxApplication.java:28) [classes/:na]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:841) [jfxrt.jar:na]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182) [jfxrt.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/Edgar%20Hern%c3%a1ndez/Documents/Programacion/GIT%20repos/CondoAdmin/Spring/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO Person (id, name, lastname, dni, apartmentID) VALUES (1, 'Edgar', 'Hernandez', '26659514-k', '701'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Columna "LASTNAME" no encontrada
Column "LASTNAME" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Person (id, name, lastname, dni, apartmentID) VALUES (1, 'Edgar', 'Hernandez', '26659514-k', '701') [42122-200]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:626) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:49) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:202) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.initSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:119) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:91) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:38) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:99) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:90) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1807) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Columna "LASTNAME" no encontrada
Column "LASTNAME" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Person (id, name, lastname, dni, apartmentID) VALUES (1, 'Edgar', 'Hernandez', '26659514-k', '701') [42122-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.table.Table.getColumn(Table.java:703) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumn(Parser.java:1450) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnList(Parser.java:1435) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsertGivenTable(Parser.java:1804) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1749) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:954) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:212) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:605) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted

Exception in Application init method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application init method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:912)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/Edgar%20Hern%c3%a1ndez/Documents/Programacion/GIT%20repos/CondoAdmin/Spring/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO Person (id, name, lastname, dni, apartmentID) VALUES (1, 'Edgar', 'Hernandez', '26659514-k', '701'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Columna "LASTNAME" no encontrada
Column "LASTNAME" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Person (id, name, lastname, dni, apartmentID) VALUES (1, 'Edgar', 'Hernandez', '26659514-k', '701') [42122-200]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)
    at com.dreamseeker.JavaFxApplication.init(JavaFxApplication.java:28)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:841)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/Edgar%20Hern%c3%a1ndez/Documents/Programacion/GIT%20repos/CondoAdmin/Spring/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO Person (id, name, lastname, dni, apartmentID) VALUES (1, 'Edgar', 'Hernandez', '26659514-k', '701'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Columna "LASTNAME" no encontrada
Column "LASTNAME" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Person (id, name, lastname, dni, apartmentID) VALUES (1, 'Edgar', 'Hernandez', '26659514-k', '701') [42122-200]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:626)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.initSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:91)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:38)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1807)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Columna "LASTNAME" no encontrada
Column "LASTNAME" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Person (id, name, lastname, dni, apartmentID) VALUES (1, 'Edgar', 'Hernandez', '26659514-k', '701') [42122-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.table.Table.getColumn(Table.java:703)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumn(Parser.java:1450)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnList(Parser.java:1435)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsertGivenTable(Parser.java:1804)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1749)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:954)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:212)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:605)
    ... 32 more
```

In conclusion, H2 console works just for web projects? Am I missing a configuration?

RESOLVED:
In the comments someone passed me a link to Spring Docs where I found this piece of information:

[image]

So these are the pre-requisites to use the H2 console. In my case, this is not a web-based app, so no way José.

Comment: Please share the application.properties and Person db schema

Comment: @R.G The application.properties only has this line : _spring.h2.console.enabled=true_ . The schema is defined by the Person class which I already shared.

Comment: Under https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-sql-h2-console there are 3 prerequisites listed. Are you fullfiling all 3 of them to get the autoconfiguration of Spring Boot running?

Comment: @C.Weber My friend that's the information I needed. The problem then is because this is not a web based application. Thanks!

Comment: Well I assume you could still use the H2-Console if you provide the necessary configurations yourself. Spring Boot does this for you fullfill those 3 points. Otherwise you must take care of it yourself (never tried it myself) Starting point could be https://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#spring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Column "LASTNAME" not found`
Change `lastName` to`lastname` and try again.
I think it would have been created as `LAST_NAME` in the database schema.

EDITED:
Or you could add before lastname field declaration the @Column(name = "lastname") tag to ensure this will be the name the column will get.

Comment: Your assumption must be true because I did what was described in the edition of your comment and it worked. I can´t mark your answer as the correct one because is there still one question to answer. At the same time, due to the fact I can´t access the H2 console, I have no way to see how the column was being declared...